# Mistake in partial fraction

Tags: partial-fractions

Can anyone spot my mistake?

$$\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}}{1+\frac{3}{4}z^{-1}+\frac{1}{8}z^{-2}}$$
Set $x = z^{-1}$
$$\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}x}{1+\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{1}{8}x^{2}}$$
Multiply by 8/8 and factorise denominator
$$\frac{8-4x}{(x+2)(x+4)}$$
$$\frac{8-4x}{(x+2)(x+4)}=\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{x+4}$$
$$8-4x = A(x+4) + B(x+2)$$
Set $x = -2$
$$A = 0$$
Set $x = -4$
$$B = 4$$
Giving
$$\frac{4}{4+z^{-1}}$$

The solution says that the answer is

$$\frac{-3}{1+\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}} + \frac{4}{1+\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}}$$

Comment: Note that $8-4(-2) = 16$...

Comment: Aaaahhhh! Thanks that was probably it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a mistake in finding your $ B$

The value for $B$ should be negative.